# 80's cartoon / real-life models mix

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Okay, this might be a long shot.
I'm looking for a cartoon, could be 80's. I was very little when I saw this, so I have very little details. But as far as I remember it was a mix of cartoon, and real-life models. I.e. when seeing the crew inside vehicles (vehicles being some kind of tanks, I think), it was cartoon. But when you saw the vehicles drive around in jungle landscape, it was small models. Maybe stop-motion.

Is my memory totally wrong, or does this ring a bell to anyone?

Comment: Possibly in this list...? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Television_series_with_live_action_and_animation

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it's not listed.

Comment: To my recollection, it was sci-fi. I don't remember if the story was on another planet. But I remember the vehicles/tanks as being spaceship like. I think they fought some kind of dinosaurs or something like that. The monsters/dinosaurs might also have been stop-motion like models.

Comment: Was this a movie, a series, what?

Comment: I got a pretty clear picture of what I think this might be - but can't find anything through google

Comment: Good question Daniel, was it a series or a movie?

Comment: You got me there. I can't actually remember that. Might as well have been a movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this cartoon might be *[Dinosaur War Aizenborg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_War_Izenborg)*, which was also seen in the form of the compilation movie *Attack of the Supermonsters*.

It meets *almost* all your requirements:  it was originally made in 1977, so you could have seen it in the 80's; the protagonists had a vehicle with a tank-like mode; the vehicles were represented by live-action models, but scenes inside the vehicles with the characters were rendered with animation.

The two parts which I'm not sure match, however:

1. You mention the vehicles being in a jungle landscape.  That might happen in the main series, but no part of the compilation movie (that I can remember, anyhow) takes place in a jungle setting.  (Though the subterranean lair of the foes might have appeared jungle-y...)
2. The foes faced by the Aizenborg team (Gemini Force in the dub) are indeed dinosaurs, but they're realized largely through "suit-mation" rather than cartoons or stop-motion.

Comment: Wow! I think that is it! Amazing!

Comment: No problem!  I'll be tickled pink if that's actually the one you're thinking of - I *LOVE* AotS!

Comment: I saw some of the youtube clips. And I am pretty sure its the one. Awesome.

Comment: Oh, new discovery. After reading a fair bit of info about Aizenborg, I found another series called [Kyoryu Tankentai Born Free](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IK-ZR0ZcSOU). That was in fact the show I was looking for!

Comment: Wow, they look amazingly similar, even considering they're by the same company!